# Gradle Project Sync Failed - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have been working on an android app through android studio for about a month now. I recently got a new computer, and tried to open the app files on that computer. When I open it I get an error banner saying

> Gradle Project Sync Failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly.

When I click the try again button the error in the console reads the following:

> Error:failed to find target android-21 : 
>   C:\Users\compu\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>   Install missing platform(s) and sync project

I don't have access to the computer I created this project on. Is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: Looks to me like your sdk path is messed up...check if the android studio is pointing to the rite sdk and make sure you have api 21 installed...

Answer (score 1):

Try launching SDK Manager from AndroidStudio's menu icon then install Android 21 packages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download android-21 api
go to android sdk manager and download api 21

Answer (score 0):

This is because you might be building a project say Android 5.1 , but you don't have the required SDK i.e. API 21.

Go to your SDK manager and check if you have the required SDK downloaded. For safety download API 21, and 22 and then create the program again and see if you still get the error

or change the target from settings which is available at yours machine.

Also where exactly have you put the SDK bundle folder the one you downloaded from Android website? On your desktop?