# Android Studio 1.4.1: Gradle Project Sync Failed

Tags: android, android-studio

I imported a project created from Android Studio earlier version.  I am running Android Studio 1.4.1.

I am getting following error message:

```
Error:The SDK directory '/media/delta/f2164b84-872f-493c-9d9f-8edf44dc4428/home/delta/Android/Sdk' does not exist.

Please fix the 'sdk.dir' property in the local.properties file.
```

Open File

The SDK directory it is referring to /media/delta/f2164b84-872f-493c-9d9f-8edf44dc4428/home/delta/Android/Sdk does not exist in my machine.

I tried all suggestion proposed by:
[Gradle Project Sync Failed - Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240667/gradle-project-sync-failed-android-studio)

[image]

I change sdk.dir in local.properties file to actual sdk folder still does not work. Please help.

Comment: could try to edit the file and make it point to the correct directory ?

Comment: This file is generated, try to change the sdk path under File>Project Structure>SDK Location.

Comment: I tried editing to correct directory still pointing to old file.  Also changed in SDK location.  Still sync error.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

1. File -> project Structure into Project Structure
2. Left -> SDK Location
3. SDK location select Android SDK location (old version use Press +,
   add another sdk)

Then sync project with gradle files